# Parsing PHP in Sidebar Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm using the below funky bit of code in my functions.php to enable the execution of PHP in my sidebar:

```
// 12. Execute/Parse PHP in Sidebar Content
// =============================================================================
add_filter('widget_text','execute_php',100);
function execute_php($html){
     if(strpos($html,"<"."?php")!==false){
          ob_start();
          eval("?".">".$html);
          $html=ob_get_contents();
          ob_end_clean();
     }
     return $html;
}
```

I'm then using this code in my sidebar to reference a list of custom fields (related articles) that I want to list in the sidebar:

```
<?php $post_objects = get_field( 'related_article_list'); ?>
<?php if ( $post_objects) { ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach( $post_objects as $post): ?>
<?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
<li>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Now this code works fine in my page template and correctly lists the three related articles that I have set in each post, but in the sidebar it just generates the current post title three times.

Any ideas much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is generally not good practice to place PHP code directly in a sidebar textfield then parsing/executing its content is leaves open to many potential problem.

Instead you should place the code inside a shortcode and then place that shortcode tag inside the Widget in question. `[my_related_article_list]`

```
add_shortcode('my_related_article_list','my_related_article_list_func');

function my_related_article_list_func(){
    $post_objects = get_field( 'related_article_list');
    $html = '';
    if ( $post_objects) {
        $html = '<ul>';
        foreach( $post_objects as $post):
            $html .= '<li><a href="'.get_the_permalink($post).'">'.get_the_title($post).'</a></li>';
        endforeach;
        $html .= '</ul>';
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Concerning the fact that you see the current post three time in the sidebar has todo with the loop not have been properly set and 3 times because you probably also pulled the revisions.(i suppose)

Maybe executing the code in a shortcode could help improve your predicament in solving parts of the problem or even the whole problem.

**Edit**: Using the `setup_postdata` is unecessary since calling `get_*` functions which returns data instead of outputting it straight based on the current loop data set by `setup_postdata`. Therefor calling the `get_*` with the `$post` argument will return the appropriate context.

Comment: Thanks @Musk. I've used the shortcode method as recommended (thank you!) and it's working as before. I think the loop is working correctly as it's pulling through three related articles (and there are three), but it's using the permalink and title of the current page article, rather than of the articles it's supposed to be referencing. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Ok it could be a qwerk with the `setup_postdata` function, if you pass the `$post` var as an argument to the `get_the_permalink()` and `get_the_title()` does it solve the issue?

Comment: That's it @Musk! Thank you - all sorted!!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by @Musk using the following shortcode:

```
add_shortcode('my_related_article_list','my_related_article_list_func');
function my_related_article_list_func(){
    $post_objects = get_field( 'related_article_list');
    $html = '';
    if ( $post_objects) {
        $html = '<ul>';
        foreach( $post_objects as $post):
            $html .= '<li><a href="'.get_the_permalink($post).'">'.get_the_title($post).'</a></li>';
        endforeach;
        $html .= '</ul>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $html;
}
```